# Render status: 403 causes "Missing template" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, render, status, http-status

I have some method in `before_filter` and I try to render `status: 403`. then I get:

```
Missing template v1/examples/index, v1/base/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

I can however render `nothing: true` or `text: 'some text'` without this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the code. It looks like you are trying to render a 403 page that you don't have. Check your public folder.

Comment: Hell yeah, I should render empty json hash + status... thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Without your code it is hard to tell, but it sounds like you want to do the following:

```
render json: {}, status: :forbidden
```

Comment: such a frequent mistake. if the request format is not recognized as json it will search for a template - you solution fixes it. It should be approved